# How to control Tenma 72-2540 PS with PyVISA?

Tags: python, visa, pyvisa

I want to control Tenma 72-2540 programmable power supply with PyVISA and python script.

I can control the unit from "docklight" serial communicator. 
Instrument don't use end terminator character (\n or \r). I set read and write terminator inside pyvisa python script to none, but I still get time out error.

I can connect to device but I get error when I try to query *IDN? or any other command with response.

pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.

Why this works with "docklight" but not with "PyVISA"? I can control Keysight DMM without a problem.

```py
import visa
from pyvisa.errors import VisaIOError
import sys
import time

rm = visa.ResourceManager()

try:
    inst = rm.open_resource("ASRL5::INSTR")
    inst.timeout = 3000
    inst.read_termination = None
    inst.write_termination = None

    print("Connected to Tenma 72-2540 PS @", inst)

except VisaIOError:
    print("Error! Can't connect to Tenma 72-2540 PS")
    input("\nPress any key to Exit...")
    sys.exit()

print(inst.query("*IDN?"))
```

Comment: General tip: timeouts can occur when the instrument does not respond at all, which would be the case if the query wasn't received properly.  Check the front panel for error indicators and listen for a beep.

Comment: Sthe stop_bit is 1 by default or do you have to set it manually?